# Adding Instant Messaging (possibly XMPP) to my website on AppEngine (without using Google Login IDs)

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, chat, instant-messaging, google-talk

I have developed a dating website built on top of the Google App Engine, to which I would like to add instant messaging, and possibly/probably audio and video conferencing.

Given that the users on the website do not want to share their personal details or real contact information, I am handling all of the login information and sessions without assuming that the clients have (or even want) a google account ID or any other login that is associated with their real identity.

I would like to hear suggestions on how I could go about adding instant messaging to my website given that I cannot just directly access Google Talk or some other existing service.

Would it make sense to use XMPP for this, and if so will Google Talk or any other XMPP service provider allow me to register new user accounts without manual intervention (ie. after a user is registered on my site, automatically register them with the XMPP provider)?  Or, if not, perhaps I can use a single google ID with Google Talk with a different resource identifier for each user (me@google.com/user1, me@google.com/user2, etc...), and send messages between the different resources? Could this work, and/or would having thousands of simultaneous connections to a single account get me banned from Google Talk?

Perhaps some kind of AJAX based solution might make more sense given the fact that users are already registered on my website, but are not registered for an XMPP service?

Any suggestions about how I might approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards
-Alexander

Comment: I have spent some more time reading the XMPP App-Engine documentation (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview.html), and believe that it may already do everything that I need. At first, I didn't realize that you can register anything@app-id.appspotchat.com as an XMPP address, which is the main problem that I was having. Given that functionality, I believe that everything else should fall into place quite nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text chat is the easier problem. You can do either with or without XMPP. Without XMPP, you'll be building a Facebook chat type client on your pages that sends messages from each user to the app, and the app then shows then on the recipient's screen.(The client can be polling, or use comet when it comes out). Check out [olark](http://www.olark.com/) to see how this works.

Once you build code to use the app as a switchboard that routes the correct message to the correct person (anonymously, maybe), you can port this easily to XMPP if you require. Both parties add you.dating.site@appspotchat.com to their buddy lists, and you send all messages from girl@site.com to guy@site.com and vice-versa. (assuming a heterogeneous site.)

Audio and video, I have no clue how to do without sharing details between the parties :-/

Comment: Just thought of chatroulette... I'm sure those guys have figured out how to do audio / video anonymously. You could take a look at that.

Comment: Yes, I spent some time looking into chatroulette yesterday. Basically, I think that my architecture will be to use XMPP for the chat and maintenance of the connection, built on top of the strophe javascript/jquery library (they have very nice documentation in the form of a 400 page book). After that (as you said about chatroulette), I will use flash Cirrus (previously codename Stratus) for the peer-to-peer video and audio... of course, this could all change as I uncover the warts of the various technologies along the way...

Comment: Hmmm. I had no idea these libraries existed... thanks for the tip.

Comment: I forgot to mention one more library that is designed on top of Cirrus/Flash and appears to allow you to directly embed video and audio into javascript running in a browser (which could be perfect for my chat+video/audio).  http://myprojectguide.org/p/flash-videoio/1.html. -- but, I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks... starred this question so I can find it again when I get around to doing video.